# inequality involving exponentials and square root function

Tags: calculus, inequality, exponential-function

I came across the following inequality from [these notes](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Emjwain/stat210b/Chap2_TailBounds_Jan22_2015.pdf). It states that
$\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\sqrt{1-2\lambda}} \le e^{2\lambda^2}$ for $\lambda < \frac{1}{4}$.

Is there a way to show this using calculus? I tried setting $f(\lambda) = e^{2\lambda^2} -\frac{e^{-\lambda}}{\sqrt{1-2\lambda}} $. Since $f(0) = 0$, I tried showing that at least for $\lambda \in (0,\frac{1}{4}), f'(\lambda) > 0$ so that $f(\lambda) > 0$. However, it doesn't seem straightforward to show this.

Are there other alternative approaches to show this inequality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take
$$
g(\lambda)=\sqrt{1-2\lambda}e^{2\lambda^2+\lambda}
$$
and we want to show that $g(\lambda)\ge 1$ for $\lambda\in (0,1/4)$. Note that $g(0)=1$. Then we use the product rule to calculate
$$
g'(\lambda)=\frac{-g(\lambda)}{1-2\lambda}+(4\lambda+1)g(\lambda)
$$
and we want to show that this is positive, that is
$$
(4\lambda+1)\ge \frac{1}{1-2\lambda}
$$
We multiply to clear the denominator, and we get that we need $\lambda$ to satisfy
$$
-8\lambda^2+2\lambda\ge 0
$$
which it does for $\lambda\in (0,1/4)$.

Comment: Thanks! The calculations involved here are much cleaner!